# The min () to improve

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my database project.

table **user_**

```
select id, name from user_;

 id |   name
----+----------
  1 | bartek
  2 | bartek_m
  3 | bartek_k
  4 | bartek_b
```

table **order_**

```
select id, employee_id, user_id from order_;

 id | employee_id | user_id
----+-------------+---------
  1 |           3 |       1
  2 |           4 |       1
  3 |           4 |       1
  4 |           4 |       1
  5 |           3 |       1
```

Every user has a role(I don't add table role_ here but it exist).
ID of every user with role employee can be assigned to order_.employee_id 
I need obtain user with minimum number of orders

```
select a.id, min(a.count) from (
    select u.id, count(u.id) from user_ u, order_ o
    where u.id = o.employee_id
    group by u.id
) as a group by a.id, a.count

 id | min
----+-----
  4 |   3
  3 |   2
```

I think that my query is wrong. Could anyone change query to return 
 only ID this user which have minimum number of orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like

```
SELECT u.id, count(*)
FROM user_ AS u JOIN order_ AS o ON (u.id=o.employee_id)
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1
```

(if I read you right)?

Comment: Yes, this is almost what I need. But that query be better when return only ID without count.

Comment: @BartekM, remove `, count(*)` from the select list and replace `2` with `count(*)` in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: `2` in `ORDER BY` means that the `ORDER BY` take second argument from `SELECT` and use it in sorting

Comment: Yes, so you can be more explicit about sorting and remove it from select.